# GraphQL query returning null

Tags: express-graphql

I ran this successful mutation which was saved to my MongoDB database:

```
mutation {
  addRecipe(name: "Chole Dhania Masala", category: "Indian", description: "A tasty dish", instructions: "Cook it") {
    name
    category
    description
    instructions
  }
}
```

However, when I run a query for it:

```
query {
  getAllRecipes {
    _id
    name
    category
    likes
    createdDate
  }
}
```

I am not clear on why I got:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getAllRecipes": null
  }
}
```

This is my `resolvers.js` file:

```
exports.resolvers = {
    Query: {
        getAllRecipes: async (root, args, { Recipe }) => {
            const allRecipes = await Recipe.find();
            return allRecipes;
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        addRecipe: async (root, { name, description, category, instructions, username }, { Recipe }) => {
            const newRecipe = await new Recipe({
                name,
                description,
                category,
                instructions,
                username
            }).save();
            return newRecipe;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have any `recipes`?

```
Query: {
    getAllRecipes: async (root, args, { Recipe }) => {
        const allRecipes = await Recipe.find();
        if (allRecipes) {
          return allRecipes;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, if my answer helped you, don't shy to accept it <3

Comment: Oh of course, I just had to wait the required 2 minutes before I could accept it.